# How to convert NSData to struct accurately

Tags: ios, nsdata, bluetooth-lowenergy

I Got a data from device(BLE):**<840100ec d5045715 00010014 00240018 00>**

but the **second byte** can not convert accurately. Like these:

[image]

**But I can do it use Uint8 array, Why? Thank you.**
[image]

code like these:

```
    // I got the data:<840100ec d5045715 00010014 00240018 00>

    case SPK_FEEDBACK_HistoryDataPort:
    // Log
    NSLog(@"receive data:%@", [NSData dataWithBytes:originalCommandBytes length:sizeof(D2MHistoryDataPort)]);

    // originalCommandBytes dataType:UInt8 *
    D2MHistoryDataPort *historyData = (D2MHistoryDataPort *)originalCommandBytes;

    // Log
    NSLog(@"收到硬件返回的0x%x指令(历史数据体): 历史数据包的索引:%d; 时间戳:%d; 步数:%d; 卡路里:%d; 距离:%d; 睡眠:%d; 运动时长:%d",
          historyData->cmd,
          historyData->index,
          (unsigned int)historyData->timeStamp,
          historyData->steps,
          historyData->calories,
          historyData->distance,
          historyData->sleep,
          historyData->duration);
    break;

    // I declare this struct in another class
    typedef struct {
        UInt8 cmd;
        UInt16 index;
        UInt32 timeStamp;
        UInt16 steps;// 步数
        UInt16 calories;// 卡路里
        UInt16 distance;// 距离,单位m
        UInt16 sleep;// 睡眠
        UInt16 duration;// 运动时长,单位minute
     } D2MHistoryDataPort;
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. Can you show the code where you are accessing the NsData?

Comment: Thank you for your freebck, I had update the code:)

Comment: It still isn't clear what your problem is. What is the expected output and how does it differ from what you have?

Comment: actually, I want these output:
**cmd:0x84;
index:0x0001;
timeStamp:0x5704d5ec;
steps:0x0015;
calories:0x0001;
distance:0x0014;
sleep:0x0024;
duration:0x0018;**

         but i got these like the first picture:
**cmd:0x84;
index:0xec00;
timeStamp:0x155704d5;
steps:0x0100;
calories:0x1400;
distance:0x2400;
sleep:0x1800;
duration:0x0000;**

the second byte miss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How the compiler lays out the individual fields of a struct in memory is implementation dependent. Usually the compiler has to add padding to properly align the fields and it might even reorder them (by grouping fields of the same size) to reduce the required padding and the overall size of the struct.

You can turn this behavior off using `__attribute__((packed))`:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    UInt8 cmd;
    UInt16 index;
    UInt32 timeStamp;
    UInt16 steps;// 步数
    UInt16 calories;// 卡路里
    UInt16 distance;// 距离,单位m
    UInt16 sleep;// 睡眠
    UInt16 duration;// 运动时长,单位minute
 } D2MHistoryDataPort;
```

Comment: It work for me, thank you so much. But I put the  **__attribute__((packed))** behind the 'struct'. If I put it behind 'D2MHistoryDataPort', it warning:'packed attribute ignored'. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. I've move the attribute to the correct place. It's obviously slightly different for a *typedef* versus a declaration without *typedef*. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is quite guaranteed to not work. You are trying to take a struct, assume that you can interpret it as a sequence of bytes, write it and read it back. That's not going to work. Starting with structs having different layouts between compiler versions, between 32 and 64 bit compilers, and so on. People knew in the '90s that this was a bad idea.

Use the NSCoding protocol. Or convert the data to JSON. Do NOT try to interpret structs as a sequence of bytes.

If you absolutely cannot avoid using NSData, this is how it works safely:

Step 1: Define the external data format. The external data format is NOT "whatever the compiler decided to layout my struct". The external data format is "One unsigned byte cmd; two unsigned bytes index, most significant byte first. 4 unsigned bytes time stamp, most significant byte first, meaning the number of seconds since Jan 1st 1904, ... " and so on.

Then to read the struct, get a pointer to the first byte, check that you have enough bytes, and write

```
mystruct.cmd = p [0];
mystruct.index = (p [1] << 8) | p [2];
mystruct.timeStamp = (p [3] << 24) | (p [4] << 16) ...
```

and so on.